# Unable to create LWC recipe component in the Webcomponents.dev playground

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-oss

I am trying to create the LWC OSS components in the https://webcomponents.dev/.

I created the hello.html with the below code.

```
<template>
    <ui-card title="Hello">
        <div>Hello, {greeting}!</div>

        <recipe-view-source source="recipe/hello" slot="footer">
            Bind an HTML element to a component property.
        </recipe-view-source>
    </ui-card>
</template>
```

I created the hello.js with the below code.

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Hello extends LightningElement {
    greeting = 'World';
}
```

I created the index.stories.js with the below code.

```
import "@lwc/synthetic-shadow";
import "https://unpkg.com/@salesforce-ux/design-system@2.13.1/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css";
import { createElement } from "lwc";
import Hello from "./hello";

const element = createElement('c-hello', {
            is: Hello
        });

document.body.appendChild(element);
```

But after I save the file, I am getting the below screenshot error in the webcomponents.dev console.
[image]

**Someone, please help me to resolve the issue? I have no clue what mistake I am making here.**
[image]

[image]

Comment: import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Hello extends LightningElement {
    greeting = 'World';
}

Comment: @glls, it is already there in the original post

Comment: import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class Hello extends LightningElement {
    greeting = 'World';
}

Comment: I removed the code already. Even after removing the code, I still have the same error.

Comment: what part of the code?

Comment: Import "ui/card" has been shimed. I am getting this error

Comment: Not there in html.

Comment: `<ui-card title="Hello">` doesnt exist, neither does `<recipe-view-source source="recipe/hello" slot="footer">` remove these from the html